# Uniqueness validation based on the date in a datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime

In MyModel, I am validating the `:file_id` field like this:

```
validates :file_id, :uniqueness => {:scope  => :date_uploaded}
```

The field `:date_uploaded` is a datetime field.

Is there a way to specify in the `:scope` above that I want the `:file_id` to be unique only for the date portion of the datetime in `:date_uploaded` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this, so I ended up changing the `datetime` field to a `date` field.

I know, this is not the most desireable thing to do, since it takes away the ability to convert the date to different time zones, but still worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered a similar problem. We want to record the datetime of an event, but only want to validate the uniqueness of the date. Ended up doing a before_create method in the model.rb file:

```
before_create :check_date_uniqueness

def check_date_uniqueness
   if Model.where(:datetime => self.datetime.to_date.beginning_of_day..self.datetime.to_date.end_of_day).exists?
     return false
   else
     return true
   end
end
```

Depending on your specific model something like this may be a good alternative to rails built in validations.